# How to create and edit a book review in bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was able to create reviews to book in the proper way. But I'm unable to create and edit reviews in modals.

I was able load the new review form in the modal but it only loads if a book already has reviews. If the books has no reviews then modal button won't work.

I get this error which I don't fully understand

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

pointing to the edit form line

```
<%= form_for([@book, @review], remote: true) do |f| %>
```

I've tried to implement the modals for the book model which work well but the reviews doesn't.

books_controller.rb

```
def show
  @reviews = @book.reviews
end
```

books/show.html.erb

```
<section id="reviews-section">
  <div class="review-form">
     <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mynewreview">
                Write your review
        </button>
     <% else %>
         <p>You need to <%= link_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" %> before writing a review buddy :)</p>
     <br>
     <% end %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="reviews_panel">
      <%= render @reviews %>
  </div>
</section>
```

reviews/_review.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <% if review.user_id == current_user.id %>
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editreview_<%= review.id %>">Edit Modal</button>
         <%= link_to 'Delete Review', book_review_path(review.book, review), class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger", method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'reviews/widgets/new_review_modal' %>
<%= render 'reviews/widgets/edit_review_modal' %>
```

reviews/widgets/_new_review_modal

```
<%= form_for([@book, @book.reviews.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewreview" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Review</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="rating-form">
            <label>Rating:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <p><%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: 'Write comment...', class: "form-control review-text-field" %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.button "Submit Review", class: "btn btn-success btn-sm", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Submitting Review..."} %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    $('#rating-form').raty({
        path: '/assets/',
        scoreName: 'review[rating]'
    });
</script>
```

reviews/widgets/_edit_review_modal

```
<%= form_for([@book, @review], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editreview_<%= review.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit your review</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="rating-form">
            <label>Rating:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <p><%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: 'Write comment...', class: "form-control review-text-field" %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.button "Submit Review", class: "btn btn-success btn-sm", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Submitting Review..."} %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    $('#rating-form').raty({
        path: '/assets/',
        scoreName: 'review[rating]',
        score: <%= @review.rating %>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe can help change `@review` TO `@reviews` in form definition ?

Comment: @LukasBaliak I did that and got a different error `undefined method `to_key' for #<Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000000148b9868>
Did you mean?  to_ary
               to_set`

Answer (score 0):

in reviews_controller > edit action you must find @book and @review as well.

```
def edit
  @review = @book.reviews.find(params[:id])
end
```

It looks like you are showing all reviews in show page of book. and you want to do edit with ajax. In that case you must be using some kind of loop and you must be assigning a single review object to any variable. you need to use that variable in form object

```
<%= @reviewes.each do |review| %>
  <% form_for [@book, review] ... do %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If I get your answer, you said I should adjust my reviews#edit action which I have done. And for the second loop, since I already have the `_review.html.erb` partial rendered on the books show page. Can you please explain a bit more? And BTW, do you know why my question was downvoted? thanks!

Comment: Don't have idea why it was down voted. use debugger in partial and check what is the value of `@review`. `@review` is not defined as I see. you can also replace `render 'reviews/widgets/edit_review_modal'` with `render 'reviews/widgets/edit_review_modal', review: review` and in partial use `review` instead of `@review`